# Is accesses to a variable length memory object through a struct well defined?

Tags: c, struct

I have a variable-length data record that I model with a struct. Given a memory object, I'm wondering if the following is well defined in the C standard.

I model the problem with the following structure:

```
struct record
{
   uint32_t type;
   union
   {
     uint8_t u8;
     uint16_t u16;
     uint34_t u32;
   };
};
```

For the platform in question,

```
sizeof(struct record) == 8
```

Would the following casting be well defined?

```
alignas(uint32_t) uint8_t buf[5];
struct record *rec = (struct record*)buffer;
```

How about accesses to the memory object through the pointer. That is, are the accesses

```
uint8_t x = rec->u8;
rec->u8 = x+1;
```

well defined? I fully expect u16 and u32 accesses not to be well defined and may cause exception.

Reference to the c11 standard would be appreciated.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `uint34_t `? I guess you meant `uint32_t`

Comment: What is `buffer`? - not defined in your question.

Answer (score 0):

### Aliasing Violation

Regarding:

```
alignas(uint32_t) uint8_t buf[5];
struct record *rec = (struct record*)buf;
uint8_t x = rec->u8;
```

(Note that `buffer` in the original was apparently a mistake and has been corrected to `buf` here.)

This violates C 2018 6.5 7 (C 2011 has the same text), which says:

> An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue expression that has one of the following types:
>
> — a type compatible with the effective type of the object,
>
> — a qualified version of a type compatible with the effective type of the object,
>
> — a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the effective type of the object,
>
> — a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to a qualified version of the effective type of the object,
>
> — an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its members (including, recursively, a member of a subaggregate or contained union), or
>
> — a character type.

`buf` is an array of 5 `uint8_t`. It is accessed through `rec`, which a `struct record`. Comparing this to the cases listed above:

- `struct record` is not compatible with array of 5 `uint8_t`.
- `struct record` is not a qualified version of a type compatible with array of 5 `uint8_t`.
- `struct record` is not a signed or unsigned type corresponding to array of 5 `uint8_t`.
- `struct record` is an aggregate union type, but none of its members is compatible with array of 5 `uint8_t` or any of the other cases listed above.
- `struct record` is not a character type.

There is some ambiguity or incompleteness in the C standard. One might interpret `rec->u8` as not accessing the `struct record` but rather merely using `struct record` to locate the `u8` member and then accessing that. With that interpretation, 6.5 7 may be satisfied, since `uint8_t` is almost certainly a character type and hence satisfies the last case. (It must be a character type unless the implementation defines an extended integer type for it.) I would not rely on this interpretation of the C standard. However, the `u16` and `u32` members would not match any case, so using them would definitely violate C 2018 6.5 7.

### Solution

A proper way to interpret the bytes in `buf` as desired is to copy them into a structure:

```
#include <string.h> // For memcpy.
…
struct record MyRecord;
memcpy(MyRecord, buf, SomeLength);
```

### Other Issues

The title asks about a “variable length memory object”, but the size of `buf` is 5 bytes and does not vary.

In `alignas(uint32_t) uint8_t buf[5];`, if it were going to work, the `alignas` would better have been `alignas(struct record)`.

Comment: If the `buf` is of type `char` and the size is calculated correctly (char is not always the same as uint8_t) then the casting should also work in a standard way, even without alignment.  For alignment one can  use posix_memalign().

Comment: @Serge: Without proper alignment, the behavior of the conversion may be undefined. Per C 2018 6.3.2.3 7, “A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a different object type. If the resulting pointer is not correctly aligned for the referenced type, the behavior is undefined.” Additionally, the aliasing violation remains, even if the pointer conversion works.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Does it matter that the memory object (assume sizeof(buf) == 5) is smaller that the record (sizeof(struct record)==8)? That is, as long as I limit all access to the valid region of the memory object?

Comment: @Tom: The size of the object would a problem for certain forms of aliasing and not for others. For example, if you are trying to access `buf` with a `rec` that is a pointer to a structure, and the structure is larger than `buf`, then `*rec` cannot be compatible with `buf`, and the aliasing rules must be violated. But if you are trying to access `buf` with a `p` that is a character pointer, then `*p` is a permissible way to access `buf` according to the aliasing rules, as long as it points to a byte in `buf`.